# False import errors running Pylint and MyPy from vim ALE in pipenv. -- :!pylint % works -- :!mypy % works

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, pylint, pipenv, mypy

I have a project directory

```
project
    - code
        - code.py
    - tests
        - test_code.py
```

Things have worked in the past with virtualenv. I am now trying pipenv. I have this in my .vimrc

```
"python with virtualenv support
py << EOF
import os
import sys
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'Scripts/activate_this.py')
    execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF
```

That seems to work. I get my virtual environment Python with `:!python`. I can run `:!pylint` and `:!mypy`, neither of which are installed in my global Python.

`:!pylint tests\` shows no import errors, but ALE is showing import-error. A similar thing (and worse) happens with mypy. Mypy not only reports false import errors (only when run through ALE), but also misses errors that it catches through `:!mypy tests\`.

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in ALE:

```
let g:ale_python_pylint_change_directory=0
let g:ale_python_flake8_change_directory=0
```

If you do not set this, ALE will descend into project subdirectories before linting.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `let g:ale_python_auto_pipenv = 1` if you are using `pipenv` for a project. If that doesn't work for you, you can set the paths to your tools with the various options in `:help ale-python-options`.

Comment: `E149: Sorry, no help for ale-python-options`

Comment: @YzmirRamirez I bet you need to generate help tags. See the ALE README that mentions how to add a hack to vimrc to do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks @w0rp, added these two commandds to the bottom of my `~/.vimrc`:  1) `packloadall`; and 2) `silent! helptags ALL`
```