# Vim ALE cannot import python modules from pipenv

Tags: python, vim, pipenv

I have setup a virtual environment with Pipenv like so:

`$ pipenv install Flask`

then I have activated the virtual environment like so:

`$ pipenv shell`

And then I run my Flask app with:

`$ flask run`

This works, the Flask server spins up and the page is served successfully.

Then in another terminal I activate the virtual environment again and then launch `vim` and edit my flask app file.
That's when `ALE` kicks in and runs `Black` and returns `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "flask"`. Which I understand is because `flask` cannot be imported from the virtual environment (if I install `flask` outside the virtual environment then the error disappears).

I have added `let g:ale_python_auto_pipenv = 1` as suggested in a similar question (1). But that does not seem to have an effect.
I have also tried to install `Black` inside the virtual environment as suggested elsewhere, but it does not seem to do anything.

I have read elsewhere (2) that some vim plugins solve that but could not find which to install.
I have also read (2) that the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable must be set. I have tried to set it to the Pipenv virtual environment to no avail.

What should I do to make vim and ALE aware of the python packages installed in my current virtual environment made with Pipenv?
(as an aside it looks like YouCompleteMe does not complete or go to definitions of those packages as well, but I understand it could be a different solution and thus a different question.)

(1) [False import errors running Pylint and MyPy from vim ALE in pipenv. -- :!pylint % works -- :!mypy % works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486463/false-import-errors-running-pylint-and-mypy-from-vim-ale-in-pipenv-pylint)

(2) https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/issues/1998

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I don't know why, but installing mypy inside the virtualenv solves the issue. Although I would like to use the globally installed mypy.